# Copy bytes to buffer starting from nth byte of buffer in C

Tags: c

I'm very new to C and used to much higher level languages like JS and Python. I'm trying to copy some bytes to a certain position in another string of bytes.

For example, if I was trying to copy my src string into my destination string starting from the 3rd byte of my destination string, it would look like this:

```
src = "888"
dest = "Hello World!"
result = "He888 World!"
```

Comment: See memcpy or memmove

Comment: Use `dest+2` to specify that it should start at the third byte of the destination.

Comment: And `strlen(src)` is the number of bytes to copy. You'll also need to check that the copy will fit into the destination, C won't do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental copying, where you know how many bytes you want to copy, where you want to take them from, and where you want to put them, can be done with [`memcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html):

```c
#include <string.h>
```

```c
char const* src = "888";
char dest[] = "Hello World!";

memcpy(&dest[2], src, 3);

// dest now contains "He888 World!"
```

That copies 3 bytes from `src` to `&dest[2]` (which is two bytes past the start). Like most things in C, it’s up to you to make sure the operation is valid.

If the length of `src` is variable, you can use [`strlen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) to find its length:

```c
char const* src = "1234";
char dest[] = "Hello World!";

memcpy(&dest[2], src, strlen(src));

// dest now contains "He1234World!"
```

If you want to produce the result as a separate string from both inputs, you can allocate memory for a copy of the string and copy it using [`strdup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) before making any changes (this memory has to be freed with `free`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

```c
char const* src = "1234";
char const* dest = "Hello World!";
char* result = strdup(dest);

if (result == NULL) {
    fputs("failed to allocate memory\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

memcpy(&result[2], src, strlen(src));

// result now contains "He1234World!"

free(result);
```

If it’s not otherwise guaranteed that `src` will fit in `dest`, you get to experience the wonderful world of avoiding integer overflow:

```c
size_t offset = 2;

if (offset > strlen(dest) || strlen(src) > strlen(dest) - offset) {
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "src (%zu bytes) is too long to copy into dest (%zu bytes) at offset %zu",
        strlen(src), strlen(dest), offset
    );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

memcpy(&result[offset], src, strlen(src));
```

Hoping that’s not necessary for your purposes.

Comment: [memcpy](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libgcc/memcpy.c.html) is pretty unremarkable.  It's essentially `while (len--) *d++ = *s++;`  With the string functions (which I got tired arguing for), at least you have some semblance of safety.

Comment: memcpy is by far the most "I can code it better" function I see in development (for good or evil...).  If done right, it tends to copy machine word sizes instead of bytes if at all possible.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Well, you never argued for `strncpy` successfully. Like I said before, it either does the same thing as `memcpy` when passed the same length value (but less obviously and less efficiently) or the wrong thing when passed a different length value. Notably lacking is any semblance of a *difference* in safety between the two. But yes, you could use a loop instead if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try copying it byte by byte to your destination string.

```
 strcpy(result, dest);
    
 for(int i = start; i < strlen(src); i++)
 {
     result[i] = src[i - start];
 }
```

start is your nth character.

Comment: Putting `strlen` in the condition expression in a `for` loop is very slow. It changes the running time from O(n) to O(n^2). Better is: `int len = strlen(src); for (int i = start; i < len; i++)`